# jQuery selector for canvas in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I'm developing a page using the jQuery sparklines plugin.  This plugin replaces some CSV text with a canvas tag.  I have a series of span tags which contains the CSV text.  I'm trying to write a jQuery selector to select the span tags that have yet to be populated with a canvas tag:

```
<td>
    <span class="inlinesparkline">
        <canvas style=" ... " width="200" height="18"></canvas>
    </span>
<td>
<td>
    <span class="inlinesparkline">0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</span>
<td>
```

I've written:

```
$('.inlinesparkline:not(:has(canvas))')
```

However, this does not work in IE.  Since the canvas tags are generated by the plugin, I can't (easily) add a class to them to use in the selector.  Is there another way to select these "spans without canvas" tags that will work in IE?

Thanks!

Comment: IE8, but now I'm thinking my problem is deeper rooted than IE issues.  I was using jQuery 1.5.1 (thanks VS2010!), and when I bumped that up to 1.7 it did better.  Try changing the jQuery version on this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HXLVA/)

Comment: IE8 does not support the canvas tag.  Not until IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`$.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), this should work:

```
var elements = $('.inlinesparkline').filter(function(index) {
    return !$(this).find('canvas').length;
});
```

It will filter out each each `.inliensparkline` where there are *no* `<canvas>` elements within the element. Note that this is just a different way of doing `:not(:has())`, but this one should work in IE.

Comment: This works too, but it seems my issue is beyond jQuery/IE versions.